# Increasing number of rows after merging 2 csv files with same number of rows

Tags: r, csv, merge

I'm just starting in R, and this probably is really simple, but here we go: 
I'm merging 2 csv files with the same number of rows by a common column "IID". The number of rows for each of the csv files is 566. When I perform the merge, this amounts to 568. Why is that? Is there anything being double counted?

```
data1<-read.csv("lala1.csv", head=T,sep=",")
data2<-read.csv("lala2.csv", head=T,sep=",")
dataMerge<-merge(data1,data2,by="IID")
write.csv(dataMerge, "lala_All_.csv")
```

## data1

`.   FID     IID                              T1
1     1   26014                      0.004755930
2     1   31935                      0.006217750
3     2   27841                      0.005631550
4     2   32400                      0.004967280
5     3   28814                      0.005395390
6     3   33276                      0.005683260
7     4   29445                      0.005079630
8     5   28593                      0.004365470
9     5   29851                      0.005743720
10    6   29852                      0.004015790
11    6   31820                      0.005455630
12    7   33386                      0.005741080
13    7   37065                      0.006015120
14    8   33475                      0.004334330
15    8   38487                      0.004427610
16    9   34157                      0.004991320
17    9   39281                      0.005380730
18   10   36963                      0.005759670
19   10   39673                      0.003827710
20   11   36964                      0.006559190`

## data2

`.   FID     IID                             T2
1     1   26014                      0.009336160
2     1   31935                      0.011135400
3     2   27841                      0.010364200
4     2   32400                      0.009077190
5     3   28814                      0.009483640
6     3   33276                      0.009537670
7     4   29445                      0.009054180
8     5   28593                      0.008029250
9     5   29851                      0.010172700
10    6   29852                      0.006687910
11    6   31820                      0.009435050
12    7   33386                      0.010146600
13    7   37065                      0.010533700
14    8   33475                      0.007430050
15    8   38487                      0.008475400
16    9   34157                      0.008564570
17    9   39281                      0.009678990
18   10   36963                      0.010390400
19   10   39673                      0.006431420
20   11   36964                      0.011702000`

Comment: If there is an `"IID"` **value** in one but not the other, then a new row will be created.

Comment: there is an IID column in both files.

Comment: You likely have duplicated or missing IID in one or both of the tables. Look at `anyDuplicated(data1$IID)` and `anyDuplicated(data2$IID)` But really this stuff is just guess work without a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a problem with mismatched `IIDD`.  Consider these examples.

```
df1 <- data.frame(IIDD = c("A", "B", "c", "D"), trait = c('x', 'x', 'x', 'x'))
df2 <- data.frame(IIDD = c("A", "B", "c", "E"), sales = c(400, 200, 700, 500))
df3 <- data.frame(IIDD = c("A", "B", "c", "C"), sales = c(400, 200, 700, 500))
```

Use the `all.equal` and `unique` functions to test.

```
all.equal(unique(df1$IIDD), unique(df2$IIDD))
all.equal(unique(df1$IIDD), unique(df3$IIDD))
```

Comment: I tried it and tested TRUE.

Comment: any variables besides `IIDD` that the data frames have in common?  Or is that the only one present in each?

Comment: FID is another common variable

Comment: run the same test with `FID` instead of `IIDD`

Comment: tried it and also TRUE :/

Comment: would really be helpful if you could post the data...ever use `dput()`?

Comment: If `FID` is in both data frames, then you are probably getting `FID.x` and `FID.y` also right?

Comment: Yes, I'm getting FID.x and FID.y . I have not used dput() before :(

Comment: I posted some of the data

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be some issue with merging and matching, why not use a join that will only include the exact values from whatever dataset you are looking to match to.  Without a reproducible data set, it makes this difficult though.  Using the same input as @pyll

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df1 %>% 
  left_join(df2, "IIDD")
df[is.na(df$sales),]
```

You can identify the exact row number of NA matches, and possibly identify your problem

Comment: I added some of the data